# Change name of currently added Node

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes, directoryservices, treenode

I am looking to change to name of the added node of a directory tree.

```
 private static TreeNode GetDirectoryNodes(string path)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var node = new TreeNode(path);
        //node.Nodes.Add("Windows");
        foreach (var directory in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            node.Nodes.Add(GetDirectoryNodes(path + "\\" +directory.ToString()));
        }


        return node;
    }
```

This will give an output like

```
C:\Test1
|
|-C:\Test1\Test1
|  |-C:\Test1\Test1\Test1
|-C:\Test1\Test2
```

however I want to show

```
C:\Test1
|
|-Test1
|  |-Test1
|-Test2
```

I have foung that if I use

```
foreach (var directory in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            node.Nodes.Add(directory.ToString());
        }
```

I will give the just the add path name but will not be recurrive for the sub directories output will be

```
 C:\Test1
|
|-Test1
|-Test2
```

So how do I get the name to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DirectoryInfo.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx) for nodes, it will give you short name without full path (and if you need you can store `FullName` in Tag). Like this:

```
var node = new TreeNode(dir.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
var node = new TreeNode(path);
```

is where the text of each node is set (to the value of `path`).

Change this out for something like

```
var node = new TreeNode(path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
```

Even better, don't do this through strings, but by passing `DirectoryInfo` objects. Then, rather than string-parsing out the directory name, you can just use the `Name` property:

```
private static TreeNode GetDirectoryNodes(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    var node = new TreeNode(dir.Name);
    foreach (var childDir in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        node.Nodes.Add(GetDirectoryNodes(childDir));
    }
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to strip out everything before the last '\' so why dont you just use the substring function FROM the index of the last '\' TO the end of the string.